# как изменить тег родителя на новый тег

Tags: javascript, jquery

как можно заменить тег родителя `<div class="parent_old>` на `<a class="parent_new">`

html:

```
<div class="parent_old">
  <div>
    <span>some text is here</span>
  </div>
<span>
```

Comment: Когда-то функцию писал для этого :D https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/0pcmgLrq/

Comment: зачем это могло понадобиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**С помощью [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):**

```js
$('.parent_old').replaceWith($('<a class="parent_new" href="#">' + $('.parent_old').html() + '</a>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_old">
  <div>
    <span>some text is here</span>
  </div>
<span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var newElement = $('<a>').addClass('parent_new').attr('href', '#').html($('.parent_old').html()); // href добавлен для наглядности
$('.parent_old').replaceWith(newElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_old">
  <div>
    <span>some text is here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```